# What to paste in when testing a sproc that takes a datetime2

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure that takes a datetime2 parameter. When I try to debug it from visual studio 2010 it asks me to enter the parameter in a textbox but I can't find the correct format. I am testing the sproc by selecting it from the SQL Server Object Explorer and choosing the "Debug Procedure..." option. A dialog appears that asks me to enter the value. I tried 20120822 but it fails with "Operand type clash: int is incompatible with datetime2". I also tried "20120822 09:00:00.0000000" but that gave me the error, "Incorrect syntax near '09'". Anyone able to help with how I should enter a date time value? I am using MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @dt datetime2
SET @dt=GETDATE()
select @dt

result is:
'2012-08-22 15:02:30.8070000'

Try giving the result shown above in single quotes.
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I needed to put the value in between single quotes. I can now test my sproc. Thanks again.